# Cannot create a task from xml for task Azure Blob Download Task. Error 0x80070057 the parameter is in correct

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016, azure-blob-storage

We have implemented an SSIS package which downloads the file from Azure blob storage. The package works when we execute from local development box. But it's failing on TEST environment.

This was working earlier both local and TEST environment. We couldn't figure out what went wrong recently.

Can somebody help us here?

Following are the software components we have installed.

SQL Server Version: 2016
SSDT : Microsoft SQL Server Data Tool Visual Studio 2017
Service Feature Pack: SQL Server 2016 Integration Services Feature Pack for Azure (x64)
Management Studio: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 17.9

Following are the properties we have setup.

Component: Azure Blob Download Task.
Properties: AzureStorageConnection.
LocalDirectory: 
BlobContainer:
FileName

Following are the error message we are seeing in the execution context.

Azure Blob Download Task:Error: There were errors during task validation.

Azure Blob Download Task:Error: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".

Azure Blob Upload Task:Error: Failed to load task "Azure Blob Upload Task", type "". The contact information for this task is "".

Loop through records:Error: Cannot create a task from XML for task "Azure Blob Upload Task", type "SSIS.ReplacementTask, {8B8C4D3B-F53C-4DCC-8D7D-6E197EE31125}" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".

Azure Blob Download Task:Error: Failed to load task "Azure Blob Download Task", type "". The contact information for this task is "".

Loop through records:Error: Cannot create a task from XML for task "Azure Blob Download Task", type "SSIS.ReplacementTask, {8B8C4D3B-F53C-4DCC-8D7D-6E197EE31125}" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, please refer to Maintenance Plan Error
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/02/16/sql-server-maintenance-plan-error-cannot-create-task-xml-task-eue-error-0x80070057-parameter-incorrect-onpreexecute/
Error: The task with the name "Data Flow Task"
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0b57adfa-0872-4cd4-85d8-40bfaa520285/error-when-executing-ssis-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Just for clarification : Have  you could try following options:
1. Try using DTexce tool to execute the package to check if this issue persist.
2. Register the Azure Blob Task into GAC manually.
3. Check if the account has permission to upload file to Azure.

Azure Blob Download Task
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/azure-blob-download-task?view=sql-server-2017

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.