# SSISDB Migration from SQL Server Integration Services - Cannot create a task from xml for task Azure Blob Download Task

Tags: azure, sql-server-2016

I have a similar problem to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613756/cannot-create-a-task-from-xml-for-task-azure-blob-download-task-error-0x8007005). Probably the same!
If I run the package using SQL Server Integration services, the package runs fine, with no issues.
Moving the package to the SSISDB catalog gives me the above error. The process is being run on the same server.

Can anyone provide any further assistance (which dll do I need to put in the GAC, if any) I can only suppose it is an Assembly missing issue or the user running the process.
I ran `gacutil -if "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\ToolsRef\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"` to put the azure storage dll in the GAC.

I have installed the SSIS Azure feature packs, as I needed these to get the SSIS functions working, but I don't think they are being recognised by the SSIS catalog.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the issue.
WHen the SSIS packages are built on our build server there were no errors but the `DTS:CreationName="CopyFromBlobTask"` was converted to `DTS:CreationName="SSIS.ReplacementTask"` this meant that when the process ran it did not know what task to create and as such the package would fail with the error `Cannot create a task from XML for task Azure Blob Download Task. Error 0x80070057 the parameter is in correct`.

All I needed to do was add the SSISAzurefeature pack on to our build server and all was well...

Hope this helps someone else if they have the issue when migrating from package deployment to project deployment...